# Test universal binary for mac

Tags: xcode, macos, testing, powerpc

I am developing a mac program in an intel mac, under OS X. It needs to be also an universal binary, so guess with Xcode one can create the universal binary (UB), am I wrong?

But my question is if there is some kind of virtual machine or such other method, so I can test whether the binary powerpc part runs ok, but I have only the intel mac.

I have also a PS3, and as it has a pwerpc proc, I wonder if the command line application could be tested here.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Xcode can make a universal binary
- It can be tested using rosetta on your intel mac. To test with rosetta, select the file in finder, select file>>get info, tick "Open using rosetta", and then start the app
- It can not be tested on your PS3

Comment: ... unless you jailbreak your PS3 and implement suitable drivers to boot Darwin, from where it should be easy enough to boot OS X...